# First caller to Promise should fetch data, subsequent should wait

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm in a situation where multiple parts of my app wants access to data. I would like the first caller to initiate a fetch from the server, whilst subsequent requests should wait for the data to be fetched. How do I do this with a Promise?

I've tried something along these lines, with no success:

```
var promise = null;
var fetchComplete = false;
var data = null;

function getData() {
  if (fetchComplete) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(data);
    });
  } else {
    if (promise === null) {
      promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getDataFromServer(function(response) { 
          fetchComplete = true;
          data = response;
        });
      });
    }
    else {
      return promise;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What is `fetchPromise`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a closure like so:

```
function getDataPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getDataFromServer(resolve);
    });
}

var getDataCached = (function() {
    var fetchPromise = null;
    return function() {
        if (!fetchPromise) { 
            // Fetch data here and populate fetchPromise with an actual promise.
            fetchPromise = getDataPromise();
        }
        return fetchPromise;
    };
})();
```

The first invokation will populate the fetchPromise closure variable, while the rest would simply return it.

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. Thanks Madara!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Correct. Done.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out we should think about what we do in case `getDataFromServer` fails

Comment: Could the promise not be cached on creation of `getDataCached` with something like `var getDataCached = (function(p) { return function() { return p; }; })(new Promise(getDataFromServer));`?

Comment: I'm confused. This will return the same promise to all requests. But the promise can only be resolved once. So jaw are the different callbacks registered?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Correct, a single promise can be attached with more than one `.then()` handler. And a promise that's already resolved will execute any `.then()` handlers attached immediately.

Comment: So you mean that if I call .then () on a resolved promise, the callback executes immediately with data even if then is called after resolution?